# CLSIDFromProgID returns wrong prog id

Tags: c++, .net, dll, com, registry

We have a .NET DLL that contains several COM classes and objects that partner companies can use. We currently use `regasm` to register the COM classes in the registry. This has worked for years.

We now want to get rid of the COM registration and use [side by side assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/about-side-by-side-assemblies-). I am currently trying to make this transition, but I seem to fail on the finish line. We deliver a sample application in C++ that uses our COM classes, and I try to get it to run without COM registration.

**.NET DLL**

In our .NET DLL, I have a class like this:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("ef828ade-b459-4446-80db-956715588601")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("MyVendor.MyClass")]
    public partial class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

**Application assembly**

The C++ sample application that shall work with this COM class has a manifest like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32"
                        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
                        version="6.0.0.0"
                        processorArchitecture="x86" 
                        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" 
                        language="*" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32"
                        name="MyComDll.X"
                        version="1.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker"
                                 uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
</assembly>
```

**DLL assembly**

And the .NET DLL itself has a manifest to expose the COM class to the outside world:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32"
                    name="MyComDll.X"
                    version="1.0.0.0" />
  <file name="MyComDll.dll">
    <comClass description="MyVendor.MyClass"
              clsid="{ef828ade-b459-4446-80db-956715588601}"
              progid="MyVendor.MyClass.1"
              threadingModel="Both">
      <progid>MyVendor.MyClass</progid>
    </comClass>
  </file>
</assembly>
```

**Using COM**

I obviously use proxy names in my code samples above, but I made sure the all names in the original code are valid.

In our sample C++ code, we are getting the CLSID and creating the instance of the class this way:

```cpp
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("MyVendor.MyClass"), &clsid);

hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, nullptr, CLSCTX_SERVER, IID_IDispatch, (void**)(&_pMyClass));
```

**What goes wrong**

I use some debug output to check the GUID that was returned from `CLSIDFromProgID()` and to check the return value. If the COM class is registered using `regasm`, the return value is `S_OK` and `clsid` is the same GUID that I specified in my .NET DLL for the class.

However, if I remove the COM registration and use the side by side assemblies with manifests as shown above, I also get the `S_OK` return value, but the GUID is something entirely different, and therefore I cannot create an instance of this class. I have not found the GUID I get from `CLSIDFromProgID()` anywhere - neither in the registry nor in my development solution.

Do you have any idea what I made have done wrong?

- I know that my C++ sample application works in general very well with our COM objects, because it works flawless, if the COM classes are registered.
- I checked every part of the manifests I created with [Microsoft's specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/assembly-manifests) and various guides.
- I do not get any SideBySide errors in the Windows Event log, so I know that the manifests are properly formatted.
- I do get an `S_OK` from `CLSIDFromProgID()`, so I know the ProgID is found - it just delivers the wrong CLSID.
- I used the function `StringFromCLSID()` to compare the CLSID that was found by `CLSIDFromProgID().

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use `MyVendor.MyClass.1` instead of `MyVendor.MyClass` when calling `CLSIDFromProgID()`? Or if you set the `progid` in the manifest to `MyVendor.MyClass` instead of `MyVendor.MyClass.1`?

Comment: Your "COM" component is really a .NET assembly, right? Is there a reason you are using comClass instead of clrClass? To expose .NET assemblies to COM through manifests, I thought you should use clrClass instead ???

Comment: [Using .Net (CLR Managed) Classes in Win32 Applications | Using CLR managed classes in unmanaged win32 applications](http://www.mazecomputer.com/sxs/help/clrclass.htm)

Comment: Use Procmon from sysinternals, filter by registry access and your .exe and you should see where that guid is coming from.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, the names are correct. If I change names ("MyVendor.MyClass.1" to "MyVendor.MyClass" or vice versa") the application won't start at all. The names are following MSDN's convention.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Yes, it is a .NET C# DLL. I had a look into clrClass today and tested it. I got the same result as with ComClasses. I always get an arbitrary ID that is not my Prog ID.

Comment: @Endgegner85 What is the actual value of the GUID you are getting when it fails?

Comment: @Endgegner85 Have you tried using mt.exe to generate a manifest for your assembly? It should put the clrClass and other attributes in there.

Comment: @Endgegner85 DId you see this article which explains the phenomena: https://www.manifestmaker.com/sxs/help/confclsid.htm

Comment: @RemyLebeau I get an arbitrary GUID. I searched for the first ones I got, but I never found anything in the registry or our projects.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson I have not seen this article. Thanks. That would mean that it is perfectly fine that I get an arbitrary GUID? Or am I too tired and mis-read it? I get an S_OK from CLSIDFromProgID with an arbitrary CLSID, but calling CoCreateInstance always fails (unless the COM object is in the registry).

Comment: I think I remember seeing this as well when I was doing Isolated COM. I could do CoCreateInstance() just fine with either CLSID. Did you try the full CoCreateInstance() after fixing up the manifest with clrClass, or did you give up once you saw the different CLSID?

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson I always tested the CoCreateInstance after obtaining the CLSID. I had a working application that I try to convert so that it can use side-by-side assemblies.

Comment: @Endgegner85 Sometimes Windows caches those manifests. At this point, all I can say is to make sure your manifest uses clrClass and not comClass. And, make sure you rebuild everything including your test EXE (or especially it). Rebuilding the test EXE could clear out the manifest cache Windows has for it (in my experience). When I did this and I had thousands of classes, I had no problems. I certainly used mt.exe to generate the manifests for my .NET assemblies, and generally, I think I kept them external so that the assembly had no internal manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to thank Joseph Willcoxson and Remy Lebeau for pushing me in the right direction!

I had a couple of minor issues in my manifests that I could resolve one after another. The big mistake I made was taking the assumption that a CLSID that I get from CLSIDFromProgID is the same as the one I specified in my .NET COM class. After it was pointed out that is not necessarily the case, I did not waste any further time and checked why calling CoCreateInstance failed. It turned several iterations of online research and testing to figure out the mistakes I made.

As Joseph pointed out, I should have used clrClass instead of comClass. I made mistakes configuring the clrClass. For instance, I used the same name for "name" that I used for "progId", but the "name" in a clrClass is the full namespace + class name.